# How to control mui List auto scroll?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing a chat feature and I found mui list very handy for the case but I am facing an issue. The issue is that the available space for the list is always 100% of the container and the messages are going below my input. Here is the image for reference.
[image: Here is the Image]
What I think might be a possible solution to this is to scroll the list every time after there is a certain number of messages in the list or to fix a maxHeight for the List. How to make it possible please suggest.

Below is the relevant code:-

```
return (
    <div>
        <CssBaseline />
          <div className={classes.section}>
            <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom component="div" sx={{ p: 2, pb: 0 }}>
              Inbox
            </Typography>
                <List sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
                  {messages.map( (item) => (
                      <ListItem button key ={item.id} ref={messageRef}>
                        <ListItemAvatar>
                          <Avatar alt="Profile Picture"  />
                        </ListItemAvatar>
                        <ListItemText  primary={item.content} secondary={item.sender} />
                      </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
          </div>
        <paperClasses className= {classes.footer}>
            <div style={{marginLeft: 'calc(1%)', backgroundColor: '#f1f3f4', borderRadius: '25px'}}>
            <Controls.Input 
                                    name = "message"
                                    label= "Send message"
                                    value= {message}
                                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                                    InputProps={{
                                      disableUnderline: true,
                                    }}
                                  />
                        <Controls.Button
                                    onClick={sendMessage}
                                    text="Send"
                                  />
            </div>
          </paperClasses>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: but did u try setting maxHeight? try showing what you have for those classes